# SIGABRT error from Flurry method

Tags: ios, xcode, sigabrt, flurry

I am having real trouble integrating a banner ad:

This line is giving me a SIGABRT error :

```
    [FlurryAds fetchAndDisplayAdForSpace:@"BANNER_MAIN_VIEW"
                                    view:self.view  size:BANNER_BOTTOM];
```

The console reads "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
" -SIGABRT error

...

i have double checked that i have imported the newest flurry frameworks:

```
#import "Flurry.h"
#import "FlurryAds.h"
#import "FlurryAdDelegate.h"
```

I am making this call from my viewController.
Whether from this method or any other method in my view controller i get the error:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
```

thanks!

Comment: Post the complete stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed it:

```
    [FlurryAds fetchAndDisplayAdForSpace:@"BANNER_MAIN_VIEW" 
                                    view:self.view 
                          viewController:self 
                                    size:BANNER_BOTTOM];
```